# Updating Content In Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have a Container View inside a View Controller. When the user presses a button the Container View is to be displayed, but the text on the Container View is based on which button the user pressed. To do this I need to update the Container View but I am not sure on how to do this.

This is my Container View Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Cancel_Button.hidden = true
        Save_Button.hidden = true

        let Storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ViewController: View = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View") as! View
        Title_String = ViewController.String
        Title_Label.text = Title_String
    }
```

And this is the code in my View Controller:

```
@IBOutlet var View_Controller_Popup: UIView!
var String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        View_Controller_Popup.hidden = true
    }

@IBAction func Button_Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let Storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ViewController: ContainerView = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Container") as! ContainerView
        self.String = "Specific Title"
        ViewController.Title_String = self.String
        self.View_Controller_Popup.hidden = false
    }
```

So how do I reload the Container View so that when a button is pressed, the Container View is displayed with label text based on the button pressed.

**Update:**

As some people cannot understand the issue I am having I will reword the problem with images.

This is my View:

Images have been deleted

As you can see there are many Buttons (with icons). When the user presses the button I want a container view to pop up showing information:

So for each button the Label text has to be different. But currently in the app the string is blank and so the Label text is empty:

I believe that this is because I am not updating the code in the container view, and so the string is still empty.

So the issue is that the container view is not displaying the title label correctly, and I think this is due to not updating the container view, but I don't actually know how to update the container view.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard then you can set your contained view controller using a an embed segue. In your containing ViewController you can get a reference to the contained view controller in `prepareForSegue` and looking for the embed segue. Once you store the reference in a property you can call functions on it any time you need.

Comment: I am using storyboard, could you show me how to do this in code?

Answer (score 2):

try using delegate protocol 
your containerView should extend parent Delegate protocol, and simply implement function with arguments func updateContent(id: Int)

```
 protocol ContentDelegate {
    func updateContent(id: Int)
 }

 class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ContentDelegate?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "containerController") {
            let containerVC = segue.destination  as!   ChildContainerViewController

            self.delegate = containerVC
        }        
    }
}

class ChildContainerViewController: UIViewController, ContentDelegate {
   func updateContent(id: Int) {
     // your code
   }
}
```

Comment: How could I do this if I don't use storyboard? In details, how to get `containerVC` without `prepare(foor segue:)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solutions for a similar type problem where I am using container view to display specific data related user selection in table view.

1. MainViewController as Base view which contains container view which is PageViewController.
2. MainViewController have 3 segmentedControl with 3 segments.
3. When a user selects new segment I need to update data inside container view to show segment related data.

Basically updating container view from it base viewController.

After searching a lot found solution :

1. Basically, container view is childViewControllers inside base ViewControllers.
2. We just need to find right childViewControllers to update data.

If you have only on contianer view :

```
let vc  = self.childViewControllers[0] as! PageViewController
vc.segment = selectedSegment
vc.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Or if you have multiple childViewControllers :

```
for controller in self.childViewControllers {
    if controller.isKind(of: PageViewController.self) {
        let vc  = controller as! PageViewController
        vc.segment = selectedSegment
        vc.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it using Swift 5. You basically iterate through the childs to get the reference of the VC you want. This works regardless if there is only one or multiple child view controllers.

```
 if let vc = children.filter({$0 is ContainerViewController}).first as? ContainerViewController {
        vc.setupView()
    }
```

Comment: Best and simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking but I will attempt to answer. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

The key here is really just your architecture. I would propose having unique action methods for each button. This would look something like:

```
@IBAction func ButtonOnePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    initializeContainerView(withTitle: "Button One Title")
}

@IBAction func ButtonTwoPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    initializeContainerView(withTitle: "Button Two Title")
}

func initializeContainerView(withTitle title: String) {
    let Storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let ViewController: ContainerView = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Container") as! ContainerView
    ViewController.Title_String = title
    self.View_Controller_Popup.hidden = false
}
```

However, if you prefer/require using the same action method between the buttons, add tags to your buttons `UIButton.tag`. Then just use a switch statement in your action method to check the sender.tag and run code for that case. This would look something like:

```
@IBAction func Button_Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case buttonOneTagValue:
        initializeContainerView(withTitle: "Button One Title")
    case buttonTwoTagValue:
        initializeContainerView(withTitle: "Button Two Title")
    default:
        break
}

func initializeContainerView(withTitle title: String) {
    let Storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let ViewController: ContainerView = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Container") as! ContainerView
    ViewController.Title_String = title
    self.View_Controller_Popup.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and other code, but I feel as if you have misunderstood the question. See my updated question.

Comment: You can try updating the container view using ViewController .view.setNeedsDisplay()

You can put this line in `initializeContainerView` as the last line.

Comment: Quickly, can you hard code a UILabel.text value to see if it is non-empty?

Comment: It seems to be working fine. I have added printing in the Container View and it is printing an empty string before and after SetNeedsDisplay().

Comment: I can send you the files to see if you can find an issue, but I am really confused as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Where are these definitions in your code? Sorry, just having trouble only seeing partial code.

Title_String = ViewController.String

Comment: Looking through now, will let you you know asap.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initializeContainerView` method, change:

```
self.Day_Period_String = title
ViewController.Title_String = self.Day_Period_String
```

to:

```
ViewController.Title_String = title
```

And in your Container View Controller, remove:

```
Title_String = ViewController.Day_Period_String
```

Lastly change this line:

```
var Title_String = String()
```

to:

```
var Title_String: String!
```

If this doesn't work, I'm going to have you add a few print lines. Unfortunately I've updated to XCode 8 (and thus Swift 3) so cannot run your code.

Comment: Ok so I added some prints around the code and it seems like the label text is being set correctly but not displaying. So the title string is not empty, the label text is not empty, yet when adding this to the text: .text = Title_String + "Testing", it only displays "Testing". So is the label not being updated correctly?

Comment: Hmm. That was why I was suggesting using setNeedsDisplay since it seemed your data was set correct as it should force UI to update. Maybe your UILabel width is too small and thus is not displaying the text? One way to confirm this is printing the UILabel width or you can add a line after initializing and updating to text to assure size fits text: Title_Label.sizeToFit()

Comment: But it is displaying text, just not the text I want it to, but when printing the label to the console it prints what I want it to print.

Comment: What text is the container view UILabel displaying? Do you have some default text added in the storyboard or something?

Comment: If I do this: self.Title_Label.text = "Text Here" it displays Text Here. If I do this: self.Title_Label.text = self.Title_String + "Text Here" it only displays Text Here.

Comment: I am at a loss unfortunately. If your code is printing before that line a value for self.Title_String, you add it in front of the other string and then only the second string is displayed, that makes no sense. Make sure you have no initial value `self.Title_Label.text = "Text here" because if so it may just be not changing from that initial value.